# Java/Regex: Negate the same character repeated twice:

Tags: java, regex

If I have the following string:

```
--l=Richmond-Hill, NYC --m=5-day --d=hourly
```

I want to match the groups:

```
--l=Richmond-Hill, NYC

--m=5-day

--d=hourly
```

I came up with the following regex:

```
(^--[a-zA-Z]=[^-]*)
```

This works when the value after the equal sign doesn't have a dash. Basically, how do I negate a double dash ?

Comment: Why do you want `[^-]` after the `=`, and not something like `\S` (any non-space character)?

Comment: Consider using a CLI parsing library e.g. https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/

Comment: @hoipolloi Thanks for the suggestion. I was considering this and also JCommander but figured it would be more educational to roll my own(this is a side project)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that maybe you wish to design some expression similar to:

```
--[a-zA-Z]=.*?(?=--|$)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aNhBGS/1/)

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class re{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = "--[a-zA-Z]=.*?(?=--|$)";
        final String string = "--l=Richmond-Hill, NYC --m=5-day --d=hourly\n"
             + "--l=Richmond-Hill, NYC\n"
             + "--m=5-day\n"
             + "--d=hourly";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: --l=Richmond-Hill, NYC 
Full match: --m=5-day 
Full match: --d=hourly
Full match: --l=Richmond-Hill, NYC
Full match: --m=5-day
Full match: --d=hourly
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kRqPi2/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/kRqPi2/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can also split your string at `--` while keeping the delimiters and triming the spaces:

```
Pattern.compile("(?=--)")
       .splitAsStream("--l=Richmond-Hill, NYC --m=5-day --d=hourly")
       .map(String::trim)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```